# Parsing error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text

Tags: reactjs, jsx, lint

Why am i getting this error at the line below

```
return <div className=terra-ProgressGroup> {GroupProgressBar} </div>
```

41:27  error  Parsing error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the error message says, the value of an attribute must either be an expression

```
attr={...}
```

or quoted

```
attr="..."
```

[Official documentation.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-attributes-with-jsx)

Answer (score 9):

If you are trying to use `template literals` , just wrapped them in ``` {``} ```

```
return <div className={`now it ${works}`}> Hello World </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just put quotes around it, like this: `<script src="IT WORKS!"></script>`